# Android Library project building jar with resources using ant

Tags: android, ant, jar, building

Android project referencing to multiple libraries, with resource files.

I want to generate a jar with resource files from the library project and want to  use it in

main android project, am not using eclipse, I want this to be done through ant .

Is it possible, because I checked few sites, where they have given to delete the src

and distributing it as zip.

If its possible please give me the process how to go with building through ant.

Answer (score 2):

As far I know this is not possible. Android does not package xml files or drawables in jar files and you cannot access them from another project. You could look at *.aar files, which were introduced last year. But it only works with the Gradle system and Android Studio. It can contain xml and drawable resources from your project.